# Transparent PNG not working in SQL Server Image field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dynamic-data

I have tried uploading a transparent PNG image to a SQL server image field, and retrieving it using the DynamicData ImageHandler. The Transparent areas in the image appear white upon rendering. Please advise about any solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the content type of the returned response from the handler. After setting the content type to image/png, it worked

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tom, I could hardly believe that SQL would change the image, giving the problems you are experiencing.
Furthermore, why storing the images in a SQL server image field? You should have a real good reason for doing so, because otherwise it's better (in my experience) to store a reference to the file in a varchar field.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BLOB directly and put the image's raw data into that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I suspect that ImageHandler is manipulating your image in a way that causes the transparency to disappear.